# HP 630: Changed hdd to ssd -> no disk drive detected

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

I have just installed an SSD (toshiba q300pro  256 GB precisely) into my HP 630 notebook. The original HDD just got slower and slower and I wasn't satisfied with it anymore.

The installation process itself was nice and hasslefree. I properly attached the SATA power+data cable (on cable with both sata pins) and remounted everything.

After booting I got the message "No bootable device  insert boot disk and press any key".  That seemed logical as the new drive is completely empty. After booting  a backup recovery DVD however I got the message "No hard disk drive found" (ease Us TodoBackup). The same message was returned by the live CD of Acronis Disk Director.

Entering BIOS (InsydeH20 Setup Utility Rev. 3.5) I did not found any information on the detected hard drives as I get in AMI BIOS or comparable.  I ran the "Primary Hard Disk Self Test" in the menu "Diagnostics"....that ran for about 5 minutes and told me "Test passed" at the end. I have no idea what that test actually does anything.

Is there anything I can do to remedy the situation? I am pretty sure that the physical cable is OK...double checked it. Could the drive be incompatible for any reason but why? Of course I could try attaching it to my computer to check if the drive itself is OK but I really doubt that this could be the reason for the error.

Should I perform a BIOS Update? Once I ruined my complete computer by doing such an update thus I am reluctant to proceed that way.

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem myself. It turned out that the programs I first used were both unable to handle a disk without partition table. After booting a livecd of GParted I was able to create a partition and do the recovery then.